# Boot Camp Assistant not accepting Windows 10 .iso file Can't figure out Plist

Tags: windows, boot-camp

I have tried browsing the other answers to this but I still can't seem to figure this out. It may be beyond my scope.

My Mac:  Mid 2012 Mac Book Pro
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro9,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2.5 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1

I have downloaded the Windows 10.ISO from Microsoft website. I am getting the error message regarding "only supports Windows 7 or later installation on this platform. Please use an ISO file for Windows 7 or later installation."

I had tried following the tips to edit the Plist file of Bootcamp, but I can't find my model in the Plist file or even find the category of "unsupported" in that text doc.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of macOS?